# How to make Chrome Extensions non-removable?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I want to force some extensions. I have setup **ExtensionInstallForcelist** in Registry. The problem is with the Profiles and the Primary accounts associated with Profiles. I want to add only one Profile with a certain account and I want to make that Profile non-deletable and also prevent logged account from signing out. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Chrome Enterprise](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202?hl=en) to set up a policy that forces a particular extension to be installed.